# Buildbot does not start with default configuration

Tags: python, buildbot, twistd

Thought I'd give buildbot a try. So I followed the tutorial, doing these:

`sudo pip install virtualenv 'buildbot[bundle]'
 virtualenv bb-master
 source bb-master/bin/activate
 buildbot create-master master
 buildbot start`

All goes well until that last command, when I get:

> Following twistd.log until startup finished..
>   The buildmaster took more than 10 seconds to start, so we were unable to confirm
>   that it started correctly. Please 'tail twistd.log' and look for a line that
>   says 'BuildMaster is running' to verify correct startup.

`twistd.log` is empty, and I get no other output. I've tried adding `--nodaemon` to no avail. Does anyone else hit this issue?

Python 3.6.0, Buildbot 0.9.5, Twistd 17.1.0, Arch Linux (tried on Alpine v3.5 too with the same results)

Edit: in addition to the steps above I also renamed master.cfg.sample to master.cfg as specified in the instructions.

Comment: Could you point me on the tutorial you ran?
in the official one http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html
this is not the way you install it.
Here you installed buildbot globally, then created an empty virtualenv
You also need to copy the master.cfg

Comment: I've updated the question; I did rename master.cfg as you've pointed out. The way I install it should be irrelevant; if there is a problem I would expect buildbot to bomb out with an error message! The versions of everything I have are up to date and they (twistd/virtualenv) are all working fine as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was installing it under Python 3, [which is not yet supported](https://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/installation/requirements.html).

In my defence the [tutorial](https://docs.buildbot.net/latest/tutorial/firstrun.html#goal) is a little unclear as it includes sections for Python 2 and Python 3 when talking about `virtualenv`. In any case, I'm now up and running!

Comment: buildbot 0.9.5 do supports python3. That part of the doc should be updated